# Oracle replace string inside CLOB with sql as value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with `CLOB` datatype with `SQL` script as value. I want to replace the string inside the `sql` script value. Please see the below scenario that I'm looking to know:

I have a table called `TEST` with columns `NAME, DEPT_SQL` with the below value inside the table:

**DEPT_SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM DEPT WHERE DEPT_NAME IN('SALES','MARKETING','FINANCE','IT')
```

Now, I would like to replace the 'SALES' value with many values `'TODAY_SALES','WEEK_SALES','MONTH_SALES'` inside the `sql` script column value.

Could anyone help me to know about the replacement of single string value with multiple string values?

I tried the below approach but it's giving the proper string to replace:

```
SELECT name, to_clob(replace(dept_sql,'SALES','TODAY_SALES, WEEK_SALES, MONTH_SALES')) as sql
from test
where sql like '%SALES%' and name='CLOSE'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your replace can be simplified with [alternate quoting mechanism](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html) (using `q`) for quotes

```
SELECT replace(dept_sql, q'{'SALES'}', 
       q'{'TODAY_SALES','WEEK_SALES','MONTH_SALES'}') as sql
FROM   test;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=13670f09d12b3b0eb9bec5cade17e473)

Comment: @DIVA : You're welcome. If you think the answer worked for you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as it would also help others seeking solutions.